# Form is not working after ComboBox selected

Tags: c#, winforms

After Combobox is selected, my C# Windows Form is not working anymore. (Such as TextBox, DateBox, GridView, Button ..etc) nothing can do in Windows Form. How can I solve this?

Comment: What you meant by `not Working`? do you have anything written in the selectedIndex_changed event for the combobox? if possible then share the code with us

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question, but it is still rather unclear. Please [edit] it further. You should include some of your code code. If possible, create a [mcve]. Maybe if we can see your code, we can find out where the problem is.

Comment: You need to post some code.  Are you doing some blocking operation, such as database read, when selecting from your combobox?

Comment: may be it was breakpoint or some exception, than you not see. user interface can not just not work